# MySQL Regexp for uk postal area

Tags: mysql, regex

I need all the postcodes where the postal area (first letters) matches my string.

Example postcodes:

```
SW12 3AB
S12 3AB
```

If my postal area string is 's' it should only return `S12 3AB`.

If my postal area string is 'sw' it should only return `SW12 3AB`.

This is my query:

```
SELECT ID, Postcode
FROM order 
WHERE Postcode REGEXP '^s[0-9].*'
```

After spending hours reading the manual I see no problems with this syntax.
- Postcode must start with my string
- the string must be followed by a number
- and anything can happen after

Unfortunately does not return any records. What do I do wrong?

Comment: Might it be that your `s` in `'^s[0-9].*'` is lower case while in the postcodes it is an upper case `S`? Most regex-flavours are case-sensitive by default. Try `'^[sS][0-9]'` (you can ommit the `.*` since you're not matching the end of the string).

Comment: @funkwurm,  omitting `.*` was a good tip, thanks. Unfortunately case sensitiveness in not an issue. Tried in many ways...

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem and I feel so silly.

There are no UK postcode area "S", therefore it did not find any match.

It works perfectly with these "N" and "NW" and all the other valid areas.